# Mean and Variance for a random variable that is a product of two other random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

We have independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, and variances $\sigma_{1}^{2}$ and $\sigma_2^2$, respectively. Let $Y$ be a random variable such that $Y=X_1X_2$. We want to show that the mean of $Y$ is $\mu_1\mu_2$ and variance is $\sigma_{1}^{2}\sigma_2^2+\mu_1^2\sigma_2^2+\mu_2^2\sigma_{1}^{2}$. The mean part is pretty straightforward since expectation is a linear operator. However, I am struggling to prove the variance part. Any help or hint will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $E(X_1 X_2)=\mu_1\mu_2$ because $X_1,X_2$ are independent and not because of the linearity of the operator. $E(X_1+X_2)=\mu_1+\mu_2$ because of the linearity.

Now for the variance...

1. $V(Y)=E(Y^2)-[E(Y)]^2$, with $Y=X_1 X_2$ and $X_1,X_2$ independent.
2. $V(X_1 X_2)=E(X_1^2 X_2^2)-[E(X_1 X_2)]^2$
3. Due to independence, $V(X_1 X_2)=E(X_1^2)E(X_2^2)-\mu_1^2\mu_2^2$
4. But $E(X_i^2)=V(X_i)+\mu_i^2$ and $V(X_1 X_2)=(\sigma_1^2+\mu_1^2)(\sigma_2^2+\mu_2^2)-\mu_1^2\mu_2^2$.

Just develop this last expression to get your result.

It is interesting to notice that when $X_1,X_2$ are independent, with  $E(X_1)=E(X_2)=0$ it holds that: $V(X_1 X_2)=V(X_1)V(X_2)$.